# DOM.getElementById in GWT doesn't seem to work

Tags: gwt, getelementbyid

I've the following code snippet:

```
myPanel.getElement().setId("left-content");
//...
//...
Element e = DOM.getElementById("left-content");// this returns NULL!
```

### Update

Here is a longer code snippet:

```
public class RootComposite extends Composite
{
    public RootComposite(int comboSelectedIndex)
    {

        VerticalPanel verticalPanel = new VerticalPanel();
        initWidget(verticalPanel);
        VerticalPanel containerPanel = new VerticalPanel();
        containerPanel.setSpacing(1);
        verticalPanel.add(containerPanel);
        verticalPanel.setSize("100%", "100%");

        RightPanelMainComposite rightPanelMainComposite =  new RightPanelMainComposite();

        VerticalPanel rightcolVerticalPanel = new VerticalPanel();
        rightcolVerticalPanel.setStyleName("rightcol");
        VerticalPanel searchVerticalPanel = new VerticalPanel();
        searchVerticalPanel.setStyleName("search");
        rightcolVerticalPanel.add(searchVerticalPanel);
        searchVerticalPanel.add(rightPanelMainComposite);

        ContentComposite contentComposite = new ContentComposite();

        HorizontalPanel leftContentPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
        containerPanel.add(leftContentPanel);
        leftContentPanel.getElement().setAttribute("id", "left-content");

        DOM.getElementById("left-content"); // returns NULL !!!
        // ....
    }
```

The above Composite is being added to the `RootPanel`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `DOM.getElementById` only if the requested widget is actually attached to the DOM.
Your code shows that you set the `id` in the constructor and request the correspondant element right after when the widget is not attached yet. Your widget is actually attached only when its [onLoad](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.html#onLoad%28%29) method is called.

Answer (score 6):

I assume, that you didn't add myPanel to the DOM (e.g. `RootPanel.get().add(myPanel)`) before calling `DOM.getElementById("left-content")`.

Comment: i've put the actual code sniped above, please have a look. BTW, Isn't there any function that makes the current dom be flushed? (DOM.flush() :) ?)

Comment: "verticalPanel" contains "containerPanel", which contains "leftContentPanel". Ok. RootComposite also sets "verticalPanel" as its Widget. Ok. But the problem is: Your RootComposite has not been added to the DOM yet, when you call `DOM.getElementById("left-content")`. So you'll have to do something like `new RootComposite(...);`, then add the RootComposite to the DOM, and only then you can call getElementById.